# Preventing document.ready() function while unit testing

Tags: jquery, unit-testing

I'm using jQuery 1.5 and Q-Unit to do my testing.

The application I'm working on has a file that acts as an application runner, with a ready function and a few other things:

-Main.js-

```
...
var foo = new Object();
foo.bar = function () {
   /* function I'd like to test */
}
foo.ready = function () {
   /* sets up the app. I don't want this to run in my test! */
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   foo.ready();
});
...
```

Running the ready() function creates a bunch of objects I don't want floating around in my unit tests, but I still need to test `foo.bar()` and the other functions in Main.js. Can I override the ready() callback? Or is there a better solution in general? Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Comment: Oh nice. That's a great feature. I actually got the go-ahead to upgrade to 1.7 tomorrow so this should work out great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, after jQuery file is loaded, you can check if its Unit testing and then apply this

```
$.fn.ready = function() { 
//any code here, or leave it blank and all ready method will call this method instead jQuery one 
}
```

But just use it when testing.